# Add last_awarded_date to users/{id}/badges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

I'm working on an activity notification app. It would be helpful to know the date of the last award for each badge, so the app can notify of changes since the last query.

Comment: Ya. That'd be a nice addition.

Comment: Why not use [users/{id}/timeline](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/1/timeline?help) for this?  Badge awards show up there, and `fromdate` lets you filter by time.

Comment: Oh... I never thought of that... ya - that would be just as good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's an adequate work around, I'm [status-decline]-ing this.